# How Marxian economists evaluate current and future technologies for making investment decisions?

Tags: investment, technology, marxism, technological-progress

Current Marxian economists are incredibly vague about the merits of technologies and about concrete investment decisions, at least, the Western Marxian economists are.

E.g. there is book https://www.plutobooks.com/9780745344379/marx-and-the-robots/ about automation in the current world, but this book is full of negativity against automation, AI and robots. It is in opposition to the tech-optimism of the non-Marxian world.

One example of such evaluation and decision making could be this: we are living during the climate change and we should do something about that. There are at least 2 options that could be evaluated by the Marxian economists: 1) plant trees with the current technologies, that could involve lot of manual work; 2) devote some 2 years time and some amount of investment in development of tree-planting robots and then - after those 2 years - plant trees more efficiently with less human labor and more this human labor to e.g. development of cancer treatment medicines or other pressing needs.

I have seen different proposals from the Marxian economists, but these proposals: 1) do not mention the need to consciously invest into development of frontier technologies for solving some problem; 2) are not considering the choices - do it now or invest in technology and do it a bit later but more efficient.

I have lived in and studied about USSR practices and they were very fond of science and technology. The widespread belief of that country was that only through development of science and technologies the better system could be built and transitioning to the postcapitalist forms of society could happen.

This USSR attitude is in sharp contrast to current Western Marxists who are very suspicious about technology and who have no passion for the development of science and technology.

Also - I have no any information what is happening in the China governance. Do they us any models with the transitioning to socialism in mind?

So - I described that I have not found any research of current Marxians regarding the evaluation of investment decision. But **my question is - maybe someone is aware of such research - both in the Western or in the circles of China Marxists? It would be very interesting to know about such rare but very precious research?**